# Implementing sepa_king gem in a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml

I need to add SEPA Direct Debit functionality to a rails app, however I:

1. Am unfamiliar with generating xml documents
2. Am still very much learning when it comes to Ruby on Rails

I found [this gem](https://github.com/salesking/sepa_king) to but to me the documentation is unclear. Does all that code to create a direct debit object go in a config file or elsewhere? How do I call the dd object once it's created?

I tried using google to find more information about both this gem and integrating SEPA into a rails app in general but I was unsuccessful. If anybody is familiar with this topic and can help me out, or point me in the direction of other resources, I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: Not yet completely working...

I've done it like this: (see below)

So I put it into a model, called it from the controller and sent it to a file.
The conversion could simply be done via `to_xml`

```
 class MyController < ApplicationController  

  def download_sepa
    content = Pupil.sepa_for_all
    send_data content,  :filename => "sepa.xml"
  end
 end

 class Pupil < ActiveRecord::Base
  def sepa_for_all(params={})
        sdd = SEPA::DirectDebit.new(
        # Name of the initiating party and creditor, in German: "Auftraggeber"
        # String, max. 70 char
        name:       'MEIN NAME',

        # Business Identifier Code (SWIFT-Code) of the creditor
        # String, 8 or 11 char
        bic:        'BICDE33XXX',

       # International Bank Account Number of the creditor
       # String, max. 34 chars
       iban:       'DE14711081500234324766',

       # Creditor Identifier, in German: Gläubiger-Identifikationsnummer
       # String, max. 35 chars
       creditor_identifier: 'DE471108ZZ99999'
       )
       # Second: Add transactions
       sdd.add_transaction(
         # Name of the debtor, in German: "Zahlungspflichtiger"
         # String, max. 70 char
         name:                      contract.account.account_holder.asciify,
         # Put all details of the transaction in the [...] part:
  [...]
       )

       sdd.to_xml
    end
 end
```

The XML will be generated successfully but unfortunately I could not manage to accept my banking software the XML-file.
Nevertheless I hope this get's you on the right path.
T.

Comment: This is definitely a great start! Thank you so much!!

Comment: Please note that the sdd.to_xml has to be _inside_ the 'sepa_for_all' method. My indentation was wrong.